# Sanitizing user input without prepared statement

Tags: php, sql-server, mysqli

I'm integrating my website with an API that only allows me to execute MSSQL in string form. I cannot use a prepared/bound statement since the API will only accept a string.

Is escaping with mysqli_real_escape_string effective/compatible with MSSQL when I cannot execute prepared statements?

Example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE product='.mysql_real_escape_string($user_input)."'";
api($query);
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` uses a `mysqli` link to a MySQL database to escape a string according to the locale in force. `mysql_real_escape_string()` does the same for `mysql`,( the two are different). Neither will work for a connection to an MSSQL database.

Comment: The API handles connection the the database, I just pass it a query string to execute. I meant compatible as in the output syntax will not break anything where MySQL and MSSQL differ.

Comment: You misunderstand: mysqli_real_escape_string **requires** a connection to a **MySQL** database to work. It's not about syntax compatibility - the function just won't work with MSSQL.

Comment: Got it. I will encode input as a hex string as outlined in: How to escape strings in SQL Server using PHP? Thank you.

Comment: You should probably consider using a more intelligent "API" than one that just blindly executes any string you pass it. This is precisely how the whole SQL injection revolution started in the first place.